# What is the easiest way to deal with `git pull` that accidentally omitted `--rebase`?

Tags: git

When we have committed local changes in a repo that have not been published, the right thing is to do a `git pull --rebase` to integrate them with upstream. This results in a clean, linear log. If we do a `git pull`, we get ugly merges, as git keeps our commits exactly the same in a kind of side branch, and automatically applies additional changes to integrate them. These merges are unnecessary, since the changes were never published and do not have to be preserved in the same form with the same SHA hashes. It's better if they are in a nice straight line of development with upstream.

Is there an easy way to undo to the effect of `git pull` and then re-do it with `git pull --rebase`?

Preventively, is there a way to get `git pull` to require an explicit `--no-rebase` or `--rebase` in order to proceed, when there are local commits, instead of assuming a default which may be wrong?

Comment: Install [git-smart](https://github.com/geelen/git-smart) and never look back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `git reflog` and `git reset --hard` to the state before the pull, the `git rebase --pull` again.

You can also setup to automatically rebase instead of merging for new branches with:

```
git config branch.autosetuprebase always
```

and for an existing branch with

```
git config branch.*branch-name*.rebase true
```

Comment: This autosetuprebase evidently applies to the set up of new branches; you have to retroactively configure existing branches.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to try to redo it, you only need to type `git pull --rebase` once more after you type `git pull`.

Comment: ... and not type "git push" in between. :)  It's a complete toss up, but I think I will give the accept to Micha (because for one thing, it will make a visible difference in the displayed figures of Micha's rep) and the hint how not to have to do `--rebase` at all is quite valuable.

Comment: This turns out to be dubious advice. Here is what can happen if you do a `git pull` and then `git pull --rebase`: `Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files.`

Comment: I have the same issue as Kaz "error: cannot pull with rebase: Your index contains uncommitted changes. error: please commit or stash them."

Answer (score 0):

To roll HEAD and your working tree back to the previous commit, before the merge:

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```